# Which Kinect package for PC takes care of motion tracking too?

Tags: kinect

I am aware that there are opensource drivers for interfacing Kinect with the PC. My question is - the drivers at OpenKinect seems to provide only the images and depth data (from the reading of their wiki and API). It seems that you need to provide your own imaging solution.

My question is - is there any all-in-one package, with samples/sources that not only grab images from Kinect, but also do the imaging/motion detection for you?

Comment: Microsoft announced Official PC support for the Kinect is forthcoming.. Not an immediate answer but may be something worth waiting for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, look at **OpenNI** with the **NITE** module. It is created by Primesense, who are the people that microsoft licensed the Kinect technology from.
It has many compiled examples with it

**OpenNI** uses the concept of modules, **NITE** is a module created by Primesense that can track hand movement, and can understand gestures.

**OpenNI**
https://github.com/OpenNI/OpenNI

Branch i'm using (I'm on a Mac though)
https://github.com/avin2/SensorKinect